# How to change status background to be different from Navigation bar on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uikit, statusbar

I try to make status bar background as iOS6 version.
I want to use a custom color as Red or Blue color rather than Light or Default status bar background.

[image]

How about switching all text color of status bar from black to white and vice versa programmatically.

I found out that it changed after I change the value of "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES or NO.
Please give me the way to change its value programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in viewDidLoad of your projects Base class

```
UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 22)];
statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:statusBarView];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *barTintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)
```